# godocにてprivateなメンバも表示する方法について

Tags: go, godoc

godocコマンド実行時はexportedメンバ/メソッドのみがドキュメントに出力されますが
内部設計書を作成したい目的でunexportedメンバ/メソッドも出力したく思っています。

godocのhelpを見てもそれらしきオプションが見当たらなかったのですが、
javadocの-privateオプションに相当するようなunexportedメンバの出力は不可能でしょうか？

※exported/unexportedという単語は
exported→先頭大文字メンバ
unexported→先頭小文字メンバ
の意です。

Comment: `public`→`exported field/method`, `private`→`unexported field/method` などと表現する様です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問欄を修正いたしました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GoDocを使ってHTMLを出力しているのであれば、URL末尾に `?m=all` をつけると全ての宣言についてのドキュメントが表示されます。

たとえばこんな感じです。
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/?m=all

CLIで操作していて、ファイルとして出力を得たいのであれば、`godoc -url '/pkg/net/http/?m=all,text'`のようなこともできます。

詳しくは[`godoc`のGoDoc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc)に書かれています（"The presentation mode of web pages served by〜"の部分です）。

Comment: ?m=allにて全fieldが表示されることを確認しました。ありがとうございました。